# Ruby headless watir-webdriver Xvfb zombies

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, centos6, headless, xvfb

I have two apps running on a single server that perform headless browsing tasks. Each time one browses, the Xvfb process is not dying and instead becomes a zombie. I can confirm this with the following script.

```rb
require 'headless'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'yaml'

zombies_at_start = `ps axo pid=,stat= | awk '$2~/^Z/ { print $1 }'`.split("\n").count

5.times do
  begin
    d = YAML.load_file("/path/to/config/headless.yml")['build_number'] #=> "98"
    h = Headless.new(:display => d) 
    h.start
    b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    b.goto 'http://google.com'
    sleep(0.5)
  ensure
    b.close
    h.destroy
  end
  sleep(0.5)
end

zombies_at_end = `ps axo pid=,stat= | awk '$2~/^Z/ { print $1 }'`.split("\n").count

puts "Created #{zombies_at_end - zombies_at_start} more zombies." 
#=> Created 5 more zombies.
```

Why? How can I fix this?

---

Version info:

- xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.15.0-26.el6.centos.i686
- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
- ruby-2.0.0-p353
- rvm 1.25.25
- selenium-webdriver (2.45.0, 2.44.0)
- watir-webdriver (0.7.0)
- headless (2.1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** A [pull request](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/pull/59) submitted to Headless to wait by default was accepted. Woo!

---

The gem headless [changed the way it starts, stops (kills) and verifies the Xvfb process](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/commit/2886098dbf9a6ac63045a4a1fb8de40f03d5b67f). Though I'm not entirely sure why, but on CentOS 6 this causes the process to zombify. Since the `.destroy` wasn't causing issues previously, it must be related to the way headless starts the Xvfb process (which was re-written simultaneously).

However, the gem simultaneously introduced `.destroy_sync`, which waits for the process to die, and does not create zombies.

```
require 'headless'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'yaml'

zombies_at_start = `ps axo pid=,stat= | awk '$2~/^Z/ { print $1 }'`.split("\n").count

5.times do
  begin
    d = YAML.load_file("/path/to/config/headless.yml")['build_number'] #=> "98"
    h = Headless.new(:display => d) 
    h.start
    b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    b.goto 'http://google.com'
    sleep(0.5)
  ensure
    b.close
    # h.destroy
    h.destroy_sync
  end
  sleep(0.5)
end

zombies_at_end = `ps axo pid=,stat= | awk '$2~/^Z/ { print $1 }'`.split("\n").count

puts "Created #{zombies_at_end - zombies_at_start} more zombies." 
#=> Created 0 more zombies.
```